# Android: How to find the position the mouse pointer hit on the object in 3d space

Tags: android, math, matrix, opengl-es

I have trouble of finding the hitpoint on the 3d space.  I currently have viewport data which is the screen size, the depth from camera to the object (object is = plane parallel with the screen), and the mouse pointer on the screen.

I am using opengl es 2.0, how do if ind the hit point on the object which was parallel with the camera.

Setup for my camera:

```
App app  = App.getInstance();
       app.setWidth(width);
       app.setHeight(height);

       float widthDP = width;
       float heightDP = height;

       float ratio = widthDP / heightDP ;

       mShader = new SimpleShader();
       Polygon poly = Polygon.Builder()
                .addVertex(new Point(widthDP*6,heightDP*2))
                .addVertex(new Point(widthDP*6, 0))
                .addVertex(new Point(0, heightDP*2))
                .addVertex(new Point(0, 0)).build();

        Environment environment = Environment.getInstance();
        environment.setPolgyon(poly);
        environment.setScreenSize((int)widthDP, (int)heightDP);

        Camera camera = Camera.getInstance(); 
        camera.setShader(mShader);
        camera.setEye(new Point3D(widthDP*2,heightDP, -heightDP));
        camera.setLook(new Point3D(widthDP*2,heightDP,0));
        camera.setUp(new Point3D(0,1,0));

        environment.setCamera(camera);
        Matrix.frustumM(camera.getProjectionMatrix(), 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 1000);
```

This is the code I followed from the link: http://schabby.de/picking-opengl-ray-tracing/

```
App app = App.getInstance();
    Vector3D lookAt = new Vector3D(look.x, look.y, look.z);
    Vector3D position = new Vector3D(eye.x, eye.y, eye.z);
    Vector3D up = new Vector3D(this.up.x, this.up.y, this.up.z);

    Vector3D view = Vector3D.sub(lookAt, position);
    view.normalize();

    Vector3D h = view.cross(up);
    h.normalize();

    Vector3D v = h.cross(view);
    v.normalize();

    float rad = (float) (45.0f * Math.PI / 180.0f);
    float vLength = (float) Math.tan( rad / 2 ) * 1;
    float hLength = vLength * (app.getWidth() / app.getHeight());

    v.mult(vLength);
    h.mult(hLength);

    //point.x = app.getWidth() - point.x;
    //point.y = app.getHeight() - point.y;

    point.x += app.getWidth() / 2;
    point.y += app.getHeight() / 2;

    //point.x *= -1;
    //point.y *= -1;

    Log.w("point", "Width x="+app.getWidth()+" y="+app.getHeight());
    point.x /= app.getWidth() / 2;
    point.y /= app.getHeight() / 2;

    view.mult(1);
    h.mult(point.x);
    v.mult(point.y);

    view.add(h);
    view.add(v);

    Vector3D pos = Vector3D.add(position, view);
    Vector3D dir = Vector3D.sub(pos, position);

    float s = -1*pos.z / dir.z;
    float[] newPoint = new float[2];
    newPoint[0] = pos.x + dir.x *s;
    newPoint[1] = pos.y + dir.y *s;

    return new Point(newPoint[0], newPoint[1]);
```

Comment: Raypicking might be what you are locking for.

Comment: Yes that is what i wanted.. I look at the link: http://schabby.de/picking-opengl-ray-tracing/ but doesn't seems to work on me.. I re-edit the code to add some of my code.